# YouTube API : org.json.JSONException: No value for <param>

Tags: android, json, android-json

**Error while running my project**

```
 E/ChannelActivity:  New Video IdjxaQXUCdIt0
         New Video IdSz6U9KWa8s8
    W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for videoId
            at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
    W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:550)
            at android.com.demo.ChannelActivity$1.onResponse(ChannelActivity.java:73)
            at android.com.demo.ChannelActivity$1.onResponse(ChannelActivity.java:56)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
            at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
```

Here is my JSONObject Code

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject jsonVideoId=jsonObject1.getJSONObject("id");
                        JSONObject jsonsnippet= jsonObject1.getJSONObject("snippet");
                        JSONObject jsonObjectdefault = jsonsnippet.getJSONObject("thumbnails").getJSONObject("medium");
                        String videoid=jsonVideoId.getString("videoId");



                        VideoDetails videoDetails=new VideoDetails();
                        videoDetails.setVideoid(videoid);
                        videoDetails.setTitle(jsonsnippet.getString("title"));
                        videoDetails.setDescribtion(jsonsnippet.getString("description"));
                        videoDetails.setUrl(jsonObjectdefault.getString("url"));

                        videoDetailsArrayList.add(videoDetails);
```

In order to do that I  have Generated API key and pasted into my project.
**Steps for generating API Key**

Signup to google developer account using google mail

Click on create a project from dropdown icon arrow (YouTube API) at top of the page and type the project name like My YouTube Video App then click on Create button.

Go to API Manager from side menu and choose Registering your application under YouTube APIs and then click Enable API, then you will see a notice which saying Go to Credentials. Then, click that button.

The new page will appear like add credentials to your project and choose YouTube Data API v3 from which API are you using and choose Android as where will you be calling the API from. Finally choose Public data from dada accessing part and then click the button called What credentials do I need?

Then copy pasted my API key to my project.

Answer (score 1):

From your LogCat

```
   org.json.JSONException: No value for videoId
```

Seems like the JSON object doesn't contain any value/mapping for the parameter `"videoId"`.

To check if the JSON contains a certain key, use [has()](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject#has%28java.lang.String%29).

Or, you can use optString() to get an empty string if the mapping doesn't exist.

Comment: May i Know,How can we get the value for videoId??

Comment: Can you update the question by sharing the JSON object? Also confirm if the object actually contains a param called videoId.

Comment: Yes ..I Updated by sharing JSON object

Comment: I tried checking with JSON contains videoId using has() and printed in Log..It is showing false

Comment: You can convert the entire JSONObject into string and print it in log to check what the actual content of JSON is. 
If `has()` is false, then there is probably no parameter called `videoId` in the response.

Comment: Convert the entire JSONObject to string and print it to verify.

Comment: I Converted Entire JSONObject to string and printed!! I got the data,videoId is also present in that.

Comment: Are you reading from the correct node/object in the array?